# Initialize Time Machine backup without clicking the menu bar icon

Tags: time-machine

Is there a way to start 'Backup now' without going to System Preferences, enabling Time Machine Menu bar and clicking it if I have the icon hidden?

Clicking on the drive doesn't let me backup:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`tmutil` is a command line utility for "controlling and interacting with Time Machine." Try `man tmutil`. (I'm on OS X 10.10.4).

You can also control/right click on a Time Machine drive in a Finder window or sidebar. If a backup is running you can stop it, if not you can "Back Up Now."